# Drawing border around DataGridView causes issues when scrolling

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview, border, onpaint

I have a custom DataGridView that I am drawing to set the colour of the cell border and also the colour of the main border.

Here is the code I am using:

```
protected override void OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    var g = e.Graphics;
    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    var mainRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, Width - 1, Height - 1);
    g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(220, 220, 220)), mainRect);
}

protected override void OnCellPainting(DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All & ~DataGridViewPaintParts.Border);
    using (var p = new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(220, 220, 220))))
    {
        // Bottom border
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, new Point(0, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1), new Point(e.CellBounds.Right, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1));
        // Left border
        if (e.ColumnIndex > 0)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, new Point(e.CellBounds.Left, e.CellBounds.Top), new Point(e.CellBounds.Left, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1));
        }
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

It was all working fine until I needed to scroll through the DataGridView. When I scroll, the bottom border of the control moves along with the row, making it look weird.

**Before Scroll**
[image]

**After Scroll**
[image]

See how the border gets moved with the row and causes it to have two lines between the rows?

Does anyone know how I can fix this? I tried to `Invalidate()` on `OnScroll()` but that causes the bottom of the control to flicker when scrolling and you can still see the extra lines for a brief second before `Invalidate()` redraws the control.

I also tried to use the panel technique to create the border but that doesn't work properly when I am creating it as a custom control as the panel will be the parent control so I can't access any of the DataGridView methods or properties without explicitly re-declaring them in my custom control...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. There must be something else going on in your code. Try a fresh DGV subclass, adding just this code and a few lines to hook up a datasource and see if it still happens! (I use VS17Com and Win10.)

Comment: I agree with TaW, I cannot reproduce the problem you describe. After running the posted code, it appears to work as expected, using VS2015Com and Win7. The posted code does not appear to be the problem.

Comment: Thanks guys. It ended up being the BorderStyle property that was breaking it somehow. Having `BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;` in the constructor caused it to happen. When I remove this line the issue goes away. Very strange.